# Stale data in MVVM ViewModels with dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection

In my WPF application I use the MVVM pattern together with dependency injection.

The ViewModels that prepare data from the database get the repository injected into the constructor. They also populate the properties with the data from the repository in the constructor.

The ViewModels are all created in the static constructor of the ViewModelLocator class that all Views use to bind to their ViewModel.

This has the following disadvantages:

1. The data in the Views is never updated, not even when closing and re-opening them, because the ViewModel instance is always the same.
2. Upon opening the first view, all ViewModels are instantiated and the data they require loaded from the database.

I can think of two ways to solve these problems:

1. Make every ViewModel implement a method that reads the data from the database and initializes the properties - instead of doing so in the constructor. This would require calling that method every time a view is opened. This introduces [temporal coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling.aspx) which I don't like.
2. Implement the ViewModelLocator in such a way that it creates the requested ViewModel each time the corresponding property on the ViewModelLocator is called. I don't like this method, because my composition root wouldn't be executed at the start up of the program but would be spread throughout the life time of the program instance.

Is there another way to solve this problem? How are others solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Implement the ViewModelLocator in such a way that it creates the requested ViewModel each time the corresponding property on the ViewModelLocator is called.

This is more of the approach that I typically take in situations like this.  However, instead of having the ViewModelLocator composed via DI of ViewModels, I compose factories that create the ViewModel.

> I don't like this method, because my composition root wouldn't be executed at the start up of the program but would be spread throughout the life time of the program instance.

This gets "solved", at least partially, by having the composition compose factories instead of the types themselves.  The composition happens once at startup, but creation can occur at any time of the ViewModel in question.

For example, using MEF, you can switch your imports around to use [`ExportFactory<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382807%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead of their type directly.  Along with a [NonShared Creation Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.creationpolicy%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), you can construct ViewModels, as needed, and always work with fresh data, without the temporal coupling problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Having a factory for each of my ViewModels seems to be a bit of overkill as the factories would only be used in one place and are not necessary currently. Furthermore they don't do anything else than `container.Resolve` would do. As the ViewModelLocator would still be the only place the container would be used, I prefer calling `container.Resolve` over the abstract factories, because even in this case the container wouldn't leak into the application code. The only advantage of the abstract factories I can think of would be an immediate error at start up (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) if the configuration of the container wouldn't be correct.

Answer (score 0):

My abstract`ViewModelBase` base class requires an abstract RefreshDataCore() method. This method can be manually invoked by calling Refresh() on the ViewModel instance or by setting an IsDirty flag. When the ViewModel.IsVisible is true and IsDirty is set Refresh() will also be called.

This way you can have lazy refreshing of data whenever your viewmodels become visible and you can also manually invoke a refresh by calling Refresh().

Example below. (I have left INPC notifications out for simplicity)

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase
{
     //Pull your data from the repository here
     protected abstract void RefreshCore();
     public void Refresh()
     {
            RefreshCore();
            IsDirty = false;
     }

     private bool _isVisible = false;
     //DataBind this to the visibility of element "hosting" your view model
     public bool IsVisible
     {
         get { return _isVisible; }
         set
         {
              if (_isVisible == value)
                  return;


              _isVisible = value;
              if (IsVisible && IsDirty)
                   Refresh();
         }
     }

     private bool _isDirty = true;
     public bool IsDirty 
     {
         get { return _isDirty; }
         set 
         {
            if (_isDirty == value)
               return;

            _isDirty = value;
            if (IsVisible && IsDirty)
               Refresh();
         }
     }

}
```

Comment: How do you solve the temporal coupling problem?  Do you just live with it, and always call refresh as needed?

Comment: I have an ApplicationViewModel that periodically checks the state of the data and sets the appropriate IsDirty flags (but only the visible view models will actively be refreshed)

For performance reasons the ApplicationViewModel also contains the local cache of data which the other ViewModelBase instances read from in their RefreshDataCore() methods. You have complete flexibility to implement this as you need though

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I don't see the temporal coupling solved, so that's not what I am going to use.

Comment: We use a similar approach. A background thread is constantly polling the service for new/dirty data. Note that our app is **NOT** a LoB app. Most of our data is never saved and almost always changing.